# How to add CRUD table functionality to the toolbar (QUILL library)

Tags: quill, ngx-quill

I have installed ngx-quill, quill with npm install. i was wondering how to add table functionality to the toolbar like this code pen
https://codepen.io/quill/pen/QxypzX

but would appreciate if i can add this functionality as a drop down list

i have tried to add it to the DOM manually but it doesn't apply and also have tried adding it  to the Toolbar the button appears but how can i access this functionality.

```
public config = {
toolbar: [
['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],       
['blockquote', 'code-block'],

[{ header: 1 }, { header: 2 }],              
[{ list: 'ordered' }, { list: 'bullet' }],
[{ script: 'sub' }, { script: 'super' }],      
[{ indent: '-1' }, { indent: '+1' }],          
[{ direction: 'rtl' }],                        

[{ size: ['small', false, 'large', 'huge'] }],  
[{ header: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],

[{ color: [] }, { background: [] }],          
[{ font: [] }],
[{ align: [] }],

['clean'],
['table'],      // Inputted table Button

],
};
```